# Clean-up needed: [transfer]

Tags: discussion, clean-up, synonym-request

I draw your attention to the [transfer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer) tag.

7 questions. All but one look like they should simply use the [migrate-data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate-data) tag instead. Some use both tags. (The one that shouldn't use [migrate-data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate-data) is about transferring ownership of a YouTube channel between accounts.)

Perhaps it could be made a synonym?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all managed except a merged question that will need to be handled by a Moderator.

I still think it would make a decent synonym for [migrate-data].